# Как правильно передать массив в хук useState() React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Только на днях начал изучать React.js, так что не судите строго :)

Я использую функциональный подход к описанию компонентов.
Суть приложения проста: имеется кнопка "Likes" на компоненте `<Post/ >`. На кнопке должно быть написано количество лайков. При нажатии на кнопку значение увеличивается на единицу. Я реализовал это следующим образом:

```js
var newPosts=[]
function Content(){
  const [posts,setPosts] = React.useState([
  {title:'title1',
  text:'text1',
  id:1,
  likes:0,},
  ])
  newPosts = posts
  const likeFunc = (id) =>{
    
    newPosts.map((post) =>{if(post.id===id){
      post.likes++
    }})
    console.log(newPosts)
    setPosts(newPosts)
  }
```

Массив `posts` хранит в себе объекты с информацией о каждом существующем посте. Метод `setPosts()` должен изменять состояние компонента `<Content />` и передавать в него массив с текущими обновленными значениями объектов. И действительно, вывод в консоль показывает, что свойства объекта изменены. Но значение переменной на кнопке не обновляется

[image: Вывод консоли после первого нажатия]

**Немного мистики.** Если в `setPosts()` передавать тот же самый массив `newPosts`, но применить к нему метод `concat([])`, который по-факту его никак не изменяет, все сразу начинает работать правильно и на кнопке отображается нужное значение

Следующее изображение иллюстрирует результат работы такого подхода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения в консоли выводятся из `console.log(newPosts.concat([]))` (первый аутпут) и `console.log(newPosts)` (второй аутпут). Как можем заметить, они одинаковы.

**Суть вопроса**

1. Как вышло, что принимая одинаковые значения программа выдает разный результат?
2. Каким образом нужно передавать значение состояния, чтобы оно рендерилось корректно?

Извините за столь глупые вопросы, просто большинство документации о состояниях касается классовых компонентов, которые в данном случае мне не интересны. Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы :3

P.S: Ссылка на песочницу с кодом https://codepen.io/ilias_zet/pen/abBomGY?editors=0010.

Кстати, проверка показала, что `newPosts != newPosts.concat([])`

Comment: Скиньте, пожалуйста, ссылку на код (я так полагаю это у вас в песочнице)

Comment: Учитывая что `concat()` возвращает новый массив (т.е. развязывает ссылку), то можно сделать вывод что это влияет на работу. Но мне непонятно зачем вы создаете массив `newPosts` за пределами компонента, а не используете только `state`

Comment: Код какой-то совсем не похожий на react.js и предоставленный кусок кода мало о чём говорит. Могли бы вы выложить больше кода относящегося к проблеме? Даже не понятно, где компонент, а где просто функция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот рабочий код твоего примера. Я думаю если почитать код будет всё понятно, если есть вопросы задавай в коментах.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const initialState = [
    { id: 1, title: "Title1", text: "Text1", likes: 0 },
    { id: 2, title: "Title2", text: "Text2", likes: 1 },
    { id: 3, title: "Title3", text: "Text3", likes: 2 },
  ];

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(initialState);

  const likeHandler = (id) => {
    setPosts(
      posts.map((item) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, likes: item.likes + 1 } : item
      )
    );
  };

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    setPosts(posts.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Posts:
      {posts.map(({ id, title, text, likes }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <h3>{text}</h3>
          <button onClick={() => likeHandler(id)}>Likes: {likes}</button>
          <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(id)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```